# R Error Handling - how to ask whether user wants to proceed when a Warning appears

Tags: r

I am writing a function in R and managing error handling (I specifically added few warning messages).

I am wondering if there is there a way to create a question "Do you want to continue?" that would pop up in R Console each time a warning appears? In order to proceed the user would have to type "Y" (yes) in the console. Something similar to *swirl* functionality.

The goal is to make sure user saw the warning message and consciously wants to continue.

Any hint would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is a very old R question that is answered repeatedly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r is one early response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch`.

Suppose I want to convert character strings to numbers. Ordinarily, if a character vector contains some strings that can't be coerced into numbers, then calling `as.numeric` on the vector will proceed without error, but will emit a warning saying that `NA` values have been introduced by coercion.

If I want more control over this process by being explicitly asked whether to go ahead with the conversion when NAs are going to be produced by coercion, then I could do:

```r
convert_to_numeric <- function(x) {

  tryCatch({
    as.numeric(x)
    },
    warning = function(w) {
        cat("Warning!", w$message, '\n')
        cont <- readline('Do you wish to continue? [Y/N] ')
        if(cont != 'Y') stop('Aborted by user')
        return(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)))
    }
  )
}
```

Which results in the following behaviour:

```r
convert_to_numeric(c('1', '2', '3'))
#> [1] 1 2 3

convert_to_numeric(c('1', '2', 'banana'))
#> Warning! NAs introduced by coercion 
Do you wish to continue? [Y/N] Y
#> [1]  1  2 NA

convert_to_numeric(c('1', '2', 'banana'))
#> Warning! NAs introduced by coercion 
Do you wish to continue? [Y/N] N
#> Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Aborted by user
```